# IntelliJ can't find maven dependencies for GAE

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I was following along with the [Creating a Simple Hello World Backend API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world) tutorial (GAE) and all was running fine via local terminal but as soon as I opened the project in IntelliJ, IntelliJ can't build the project...

The pom file has a bunch of errors about being unable to find any dependencies, however I can still build the application just fine outside of IntelliJ.

I'm not overly familiar with Maven but I believe it is configured correctly in the IDE as I can build other generic examples generated by IntelliJ. I've attempted to re-import all dependencies but no luck...

Is there something else I need to do here?

Snippet from the pom file where both dependencies are failing to find versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>com.example.helloworld</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>

<properties>
    <app.id>your-app-id</app.id>
    <app.version>1</app.version>
    <appengine.version>${appengine.version}</appengine.version>
    <gcloud.plugin.version>0.9.58.v20150505</gcloud.plugin.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `appengine.version` property is recursively defined, so IntelliJ can't figure out what it is.  Substitute `<appengine.version>${appengine.version}</appengine.version>` with `<appengine.version>1.9.24</appengine.version>` and you should be fine.

Comment: wow simple as that. Are you able to explain why it doesn't work under the appengine.version, but does under dependency versions?

Comment: Your terminal build must be pulling it from somewhere.  Likely you're explicitly passing `appengine.version` as a command-line argument, or it's defined in a parent project, or it's defined in your settings.xml.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I do remember passing it during the initial project setup now that you mention it. Thanks again.